# Laravel cannot use 'SET' in raw SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This query works fine in mySQL client. but when putting it in Laravel, it returns

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Here is the code:

```
$result = DB::connection('main')
->select("
    SET @acc :=0;
    SELECT a.date,@acc:=@acc+sum AS total_shops FROM (
        SELECT DATE(created_at) AS date, SUM(IF(created_at BETWEEN '2016-08-08 17:00:00' AND '2016-09-05 16:59:59',1,0)) AS sum
        FROM sales_product
        WHERE status = 1
        AND DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2016-08-08 17:00:00' AND '2016-09-05 16:59:59'
        GROUP BY DATE(created_at) 
    ) AS a
");
```

Then I tried to remove 'SET @acc :=0'.  This time, there is no error. But the result shows total_shops as null instead.

result:

```
array:15 [
    0 => {#198
        +"date": "2016-08-09"
        +"total_shops": null
    }
    1 => {#205
        +"date": "2016-08-10"
        +"total_shops": null
    }
    2 => {#204
        +"date": "2016-08-11"
        +"total_shops": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

work for me.

1. create statement
2. call the statement in second raw query

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('set @rownum=0'));
$orders = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT @rownum  := @rownum  + 1 AS rownum,id)); 

$data['pacitan']=$orders;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your query string in a `DB::raw()` like so:

```
$result = DB::connection('main')->select(DB::raw("SET @acc :=0; ..."));
```

Comment: What happens when you keep the `SET @acc := 0;` but remove the reference to the variable from your query? Do you still get an error?